# PowerShell Out-String not displaying anything

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script that works on every computer I have tried it on, except my PC. I am running PowerShell version 4:

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
4      0      -1     -1
```

Why is it not working on my PC? The "???" are a delimiter for Splunk.

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"
$AllDrives = [System.IO.DriveInfo]::GetDrives() |
             Where-Object  {$_.DriveType -eq 'Fixed'}
foreach ($drive in $AllDrives) {
    Get-ChildItem -Path $drive.RootDirectory -Recurse -Include "*.*" |
        Select @{Name="Time";Expression={(Get-Date).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff')}},
               @{Name="Delim1";Expression={"???"}},
               @{Name="ComputerName";Expression={$env:COMPUTERNAME}},
               @{Name="Delim2";Expression={"???"}}, Name,
               @{Name="Delim3";Expression={"???"}}, Directory,
               @{Name="Delim4";Expression={"???"}}, CreationTime,
               @{Name="Delim5";Expression={"???"}}, LastWriteTime,
               @{Name="Delim6";Expression={"???"}}, LastAccessTime |
        Format-Table * -AutoSize -HideTableHeaders |
        Out-String -Width 4096
}
```

Comment: From Review: Are you running the same version of powershell in the other computers? What is the error message in your computer? What is the expected behavior when the script works?

Comment: Debugging 101. Remove parts from the code until you see output. The last part you have removed is connected to the cause.

Comment: Agree with Tomalak. Start with removing `$ErrorActionPreference` and possibly let PowerShell tell you what is wrong...

Comment: Debugging your issue aside, the approach you've taken is not recommended in the first place. If you can't use CSV export for some reason a better approach would be outputting your data in a loop using the [format operator](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7855.powershell-using-the-f-format-operator.aspx): `% {"{0:MM\/dd\/yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}???${env:COMPUTERNAME}???{1}???{2}???..." -f (Get-Date), $_.Name, $_.Directory, ...}`.

Comment: If I remove the "| Out-String -Width 4096" I get the expected output ( but the fields are truncated, which is what I'm trying to avoid).  If I remove '$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"' i get no errors. On the other PC's/servers I'm running a variety of versions of Powershell. It works on a VM running Windows 7 and the same powershell version( my PC is running Windows 7).  It works on a Windows 2012 server running version 5(Major),1(Minor),14409(Build), 1012(Revision). It works on a Windows 2008 server running 2(Major), 0(Minor), -1(Build), -1(Revision).